# starting Django project using cron

Tags: django, server, cron, reboot

I have a Django project which I want to start every time the device reboots. I can start the Django application manually using the following 4 commands

```
cd /home/pi/reg-sign
source djenv/bin/activate
cd /home/pi/reg-sign/mysite
python manage.py runserver 192.168.4.1:8000
```

But I cannot get this working in a crontab line.

So far I have;

```
@reboot cd /home/pi/reg-sign && /home/pi/reg-sign/djenv/bin/python /home/pi/reg-sign/mysite/manage.py python runserver 192.168.4.1:8000
```

however this does not start the server.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Comment: If you want your django server to start at each reboot I advise you to use the linux daemon

Comment: See [Deploying Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/). Using runserver in production is not safe.